# R Shiny: Defining a vector with two action buttons

Tags: r, loops, vector, shiny

im working on a shiny app. 
What i am trying to do: I want to "record" the cronological order of the activation of two different action buttons into a vector.

For example if button1 (red) is pressed twice, then button2 (black) is pressed once and then button1 (red) is pressed once again => The vector should look like: col = c("red","red","black","red").

What i did so far is this (in a lot of different variations):

`col <- NULL 
observeEvent(input$rot, {col<-c(col,"red")})
observeEvent(input$schwarz, {col<-c(col,"black")}`

input$rot und input$schwarz are the names of the action buttons. So i assumed the respective color should be added to the vector each time one of the buttons is pressed. BUT: Nothing happens...
Of course i paste the vector col in the app, that is definitely not the problem.

It would be great if somebody has an idea. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reactiveValues` to store a vector `col` on the server side:

```
geschichte <- reactiveValues(col = NULL)
```

You can then access it within a reactive context via `geschichte$col` or via `geschichte[["col"]]` and simply overwrite as if `geschichte` was a regular list:

```
 observeEvent(input$rot, {
    geschichte$col <- c(geschichte$col, "red")
  })
```

---

**Full example:**

```
library(shiny)
rm(ui) ; rm(server)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("rot", "Red"),
  actionButton("schwarz", "Black"),
  br(),
  textOutput("col")
)

server <- function(input, output) { 

  geschichte <- reactiveValues(col = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$rot, {
    geschichte$col <- c(geschichte$col, "red")
  })

  observeEvent(input$schwarz, {
    geschichte$col <- c(geschichte$col, "black")
    })

  output$col <- renderText({
    geschichte$col
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. I also tried to do it with reactive, but I obviously had no clue, is spent hours. thanks